# jQuery - Horizontal Scroller Selection

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, image

I have two pictures in a container, and I have a button selector bar under the pictures. I want to be able to select a button, and the 2 pictures will change to the next in line.

It's like a carousal, but instead of 1 picture/div changing, its 2, and I want to be able for them to slide across for animation effect:

[image]

So when I select the button next to the red one, the pictures/div will change to 2 and 3, then 3 and 4, then 4 and 5, then 5 and 6 ... well you get the idea.

Anyway, here is my code:

- [HTML](http://pastebin.com/vZwtn4sA)
- [JavaScript](http://pastebin.com/pyBHznPe)
- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverj777/Btv7V/4/)

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: I suggest you use http://www.jsfiddle.net for small snippets like these, then copy them into your main project. It also makes it much much easier to share here :)

Comment: Added the fiddle, might need some styles though.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yes... might need some

Comment: Okay, I've updated the jsFiddle with style. Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a hide method which will allow you to slide an element in and out of being displayed.

So I would create container div's for each set of images i.e. showing a pair. As your nav button (along the bottom) is hit, hide the current container shown and show the next one.

See jQuery API http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide for more detail. But it allows for direction, left/right. And mode, show/hide